# Can enter FTP using Filezilla but .NET gives "The requested URI is invalid for this FTP command."

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp, .net-4.5

I am trying to upload a file, to an external FTP server. I can access the server using FileZilla, but not in my C# program.

In my documentation, I retrieved an URL which was:

```
ftp.richrelevance.com
```

I try to access that URL in my .NET program, but get a:

```
System.Net.WebException: The requested URI is invalid for this FTP command.
```

I tried this path as well:

```
ftp://ftp.richrelevance.com
```

But get the same error.

Any idea what path the program expects?

**Filezilla settings that works**:

[image]

**Ftp code**

```
  using(var fs = File.OpenRead(zipFileName)) 
            {
                var ms = new MemoryStream();
                ms.SetLength(fs.Length);
                fs.Read(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int) fs.Length);

                FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpUrl);
                ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUid, ftpPassword);

                ftp.KeepAlive = true;
                ftp.UseBinary = true;
                ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;


                byte[] buffer = new byte[ms.Length];
                ms.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                ms.Close();

                Stream ftpstream = ftp.GetRequestStream();
                ftpstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                ftpstream.Close();
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tryed includig the ftpfile name when creating request?

```
 FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpUrl+ "/" + Path.GetFileName(zipFileName));
```

Comment: let me know if it works for you. For any help I'm here!

Comment: It worked ;) of course it did